# can't read superblock on /dev/mapper/vgdata-lvdata1

Tags: lvm

I was studying RHCSA and following steps by steps. Here's what I've done so far.

I partitioned my USB drive to 4 partitions and created 4 PVs. Then created 1 Volume Group name vgdata. I then created LV and xfs filesystem using `mkfs.xfs /dev/vgdata/lvdata1` and mounted in **/etc/fstab**. So far it's all good. I decided to un-mount using `umount /dev/mapper/vgdata-lvdata1`. When I try to mount again using `mount -a`, it show error as title.
I wonder what causes this to happen. Is it okay to `umount` device stated in **fstab**.

What is the solution and will my data be lost?

Comment: did you create filesystem on these LVs?

Comment: For a question like this it's important to include the actual commands you used. Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/714250/edit) to include them

Comment: I edited my question. I indeed make xfs filesystem this LV data. It can mount it. But when I umout and mount again, this problem arises.

Comment: Yes, it is pretty safe to umount anything specified in fstab and mount it again. But are you sure it *was* unmounted? If there were open files left it should have denied the umount. Also, if it was, did you try `xfs_check`?

Answer (score 0):

/dev/mapper/vgdata-lvdata1 is just a block device. You can't "mount" block device. Mount mounts filesystem on that device. You don't create filesystem on it so you lost nothing,
Just putting something into fstab does not means it will be mounted immediatly.

Comment: You speculate, maybe OP just do not mention it. And maybe the problem is somewhere else.